# Implicit Patter use of Unix makefile for compiling C++

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

Hi im trying to learn how to use gnu makefile and trying to use implicit pattern use in this makefile for compiling my C++ scripts:

```
CXX=g++

init : init.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<

init.o : init.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $<
```

The output for this `make init` is:  init.o (object file) and init (executable).

Then i tried to add the pattern rules:

```
CXX=g++

% : %.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $<
```

But this makefile only output the init (executable) file, why is that am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should really cut and paste (no screenshots please) the command you typed and the output you got when asking for help, and if it's not obvious explain the part of the output that is in error.

I suspect that if you look at the output from make you'll see that it's running `rm init.o`, which explains why the `.o` file is not present.

This is due to GNU make's [intermediate file](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) removal feature.  Because the `.o` is not referred to anywhere else in your makefile make decides it's not really needed for correct functioning and removes it.

The first question is, is this really a problem for you?  Do you need the `.o` file to be preserved?  What for?

The second thing is that you don't need to define these pattern rules yourself.  GNU make has built-in rules that know how to create an executable from a source file with the same prefix name.

Your entire makefile could just be:

```
CXX = g++
```

Comment: As a side note, the default "CXX" is g++. Empty makefile, or just specifying default target: "default: init" will do the job.

Comment: That's probably true on Linux but won't be true on all systems; if you really want it it's better to be explicit.  Anyway you don't even need an empty makefile: you can just delete the makefile altogether if that's what you want :).